# When will the National Education Policy 2020 (India) be implemented?

Tags: india, education

What is the implementation status of [National Education Policy 2020](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Education_Policy_2020) of India? Has the implementation been started?

And, does this policy have any implementation differences in various boards like State BSEs, CBSE, ICSE etc?

Comment: Related discussion on [vikaspedia](https://vikaspedia.in/education/policies-and-schemes/national-education-policy-2020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation has started, but is decided by individual states:

> In early August 2021, Karnataka became the first state to issue an order with regard to implementing NEP.[69]
>
> On 26 th August 2021, Madhya Pradesh implemented NEP 2020.
>
> Uttar Pradesh Chief Minister Yogi Adityanath said the National Education Policy-2020 will be implemented in phases by 2022.[70]
>
> The Telangana State government has decided to implement the newly announced National Education Policy 2020 (NEP 2020) in the State.[71]
>
> Maharashtra CM Uddhav Thackeray directs to appoint experts’ committee for implementation of new education policy.[72]
>
> Andhra Chief Minister Y.S. Jagan Mohan Reddy has directed officials of the Education Department to implement the National Education Policy 2020 in letter and spirit across the State.[73]
>
> Rajasthan Governor Kalraj Mishra said that NEP 2020 will be implemented in phased manner.[74]
>
> Assam Chief Minister Himanta Biswa Sarma said that NEP 2020 will be implemented from 1 April 2022.[75]
>
> [Source, with links to footnotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Education_Policy_2020)

Comment: ^Cross posted with the OP's edit adding the same source

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since education is a subject of concurrent list provincial governments have to give it effect. But I think even after these announcements there are not any significant changes in the education system (as dictated by NEP 2020). So this brings my second question - do states or educational boards have freedom to mend the policy according to their wishes?